# How many ways to choose 3 letters from following phrase?

Tags: probability

How many ways are there to choose three letters from the following phrase:

**MISS MISSISSIPPI NEVER EVER SIMPERS**

ignoring the order of selection.

Is this simply 31C3 or do I have to take into account that some letters repeat?

EDIT: I got 111 after counting the repeats. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: The repeats matter.  Since there are many $I's$, say, you count the sequence $III$ many times.

Comment: I also got 111.  Details posted below.

Answer (score 2):

the possible letters are $\{M,I,S,P,N,E,V,R\}$ and these occur with frequency $\{3,6,8,3,1,5,2,3\}$

Let's go by cases:

I, All three letters the same.  Can't use $N,V$ but the other six work so $\underline 6$ options

II. Two letters the same, one different.  The double letter can't be $N$ but the other seven work.  Thus we choose one of the seven, and then any one of the remaining seven (as the $N$ is an option for the stray letter).  Thus $\underline {49}$ cases.

III. All letters different.  That's just $\binom 83$ so $\underline {56}$ cases.

All told we get $$6+49+56=\fbox {111}$$

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. In general there are 120 ways to select 3 from those 8 characters but we have to exclude VVV and all combinations of NN and a third character (8 possibilities).

The 120 ways can be formalized as $C^{n+r-1}_r$ with $n=8$ and $r=3.$